# OpenDJ GET method using RestAPI gives 400 bad request response

Tags: opendj

I am trying to retrieve a record from OpenDJ using Rest API call. I am using 2.6.0 version of OpenDJ.
I am using following URL:
http://user.1000:password@opendj.example.com:8080/users/user.0?_prettyPrint=true
It always returns bad request 400 error message.
What can be the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to answer you question without further details. Most likely some configuration issue. Have you checked the error logs, http logs for more information ?

Anyway, you might get a better answer from the OpenDJ mailing list directly.

Regards,

Ludovic

Comment: yes i checked later..able to do it now.. but couldn't find out what was wrong earlier.Anyways thanks.:)